# Check if two bezier curves are coincident on some interval

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, bezier, curve

I'm trying to implement a clipping algorithm. I've already done method to determine curve-curce intersections. But now I need to find an interval where bezier curves are approximately the same. Iteration of points on curves seems too expensive to me. Is there any fast algorithm to find coincident interval?
I will be grateful if you provide pseudocode.

Edit:
[image: visualization of a problem]
I'm trying to find intervals on two bezier curves, on which curves look like they are almost the same. Clipping algorithm request such cases to be removed. I must to find overlap interval on one of the curves and remove its subcurve that corresponds to the interval. E.g. in the picture above I can remove line[0.3; 0.6] or curve[0.4; 0.7].

As I understand, I have to divide the curves into line segments of equal length and to find an interval where points of lines of both curves are located near each other.

Comment: Bezier curves are basically cubic equasions. Its the same kind of formula used in cryptography, which means they are hard to reverse engenier/solve. If you can 'solve it', it would be a major problem for most currently used security/cryptographic algorithms. So in short, the iterative approuch is the best, if not the only option you got. You can try to optimize the step-size (size between points on the equasion) to save a bit? For an indepth/codewise solution, maybe post your attempt so we can give hints from there

Comment: @n247s I was of the same opinion before I've found this publication [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282634693_Coincidence_condition_of_two_Bezier_curves_of_an_arbitrary_degree). I don't understand the math that is used there so I decided to ask for a simpler solution. I guess I should have attached this link to the question. Please, can you explain me how overlap interval is determining in that pdf

Comment: what does "approximately the same" mean? because that's not a precise enough description to implement, so your post needs to be a bit more detailed.

Comment: I am not an expert in this matter, but as far as I could decipher this paper outlines a theoretical way to check if 2 curves of the some or a different degree are simular. As it states in the conclusion, this method will brake with floating-point inprecision and a better alternative should be found for this problem. Basically it is a nice proof-of-concept, but not aplicable for computer-based solutions. Apart from that, the restrictions of the type of curves used might also be enough to not cover all the cases you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you can outline a bit more which bigger problem you are trying to resolve, as this seems like a sub-part of a bigger problem?

Comment: @n247s, thank you very much. I've updated the question. I hope, It's enough to understand my problem. I'll implement the way I mentioned in edit.

Comment: So from what I understand, in your algorithm there is no 'exact' component, its actually an aproximation which in code inherently means an iterative approuch. So either way I dont think you can cut out the iterations, but you can defenitly optimize them.

Comment: This is not two bezier curves. Also, note that "a line" is just a vector, so you can find curve intervals where its derivative "roughly" matches that vector, then check if points on it are near enough or parallel but with a notable gap between the curve and the line. Those intervals are "where the derivatives are between two bounds" so you solve `B(t)' = bound` for both bounds, using normal root finding, and then you plug the values that gives you (without needing to iterate) into your Bezier function to see if the points are near the line or not.

Comment: But that _only_ works for curve/line coincidence, not for curve/curve coincidence, so it's pretty important to update your post to make it clear _exactly_ what you need. One is fairly easy to implement, the other is a permanent graphics research topic.